# How do I isolate $k$ in the following equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I tried to isolate the unknown $k$ in the the following equation by using logarithms, but my resolution was ugly. I am trying to learn mathematics by my own (again!), because it's a beautiful subject and I used to be good at it.

This week I've gotten back to my studies in math.

I tried solving the equation $r = q ^{(i/j)^k}$ for k, but I don't know where to go from the **step 4**:

#### Step 1

$\ln(r) = (i/j)^k\ln(q)$

#### Step 2

$(i/j)^k = \ln(r)/\ln(q)$

#### Step 3

> I took the logarithms again(!).

$\ln((i/j)^k) = \ln(\ln(r)/\ln(q))$

#### Step 4

$k*\ln(i/j) = \ln(\ln(r)/\ln(q))$

**Is there any property that can help me to isolate $k$ elegantly?**

Thank you in advance!

#### I don't know if this is allowed, but THANK YOU! This is so motivating! You guys are awesome!

Comment: Looks like you've done it, no?  Just divide both sides by $\ln \frac ij$ to isolate $k$.  Or did you want something else?

Comment: Thank you, @lulu! I need advice on this important subject. Is this the correct approach to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct approach.

Comment: Yes, your method is good.   Keep in mind that whenever you divide by something you must ensure that it is not $0$.  For instance, in going from step $1$ to step $2$ you divide by $\ln q$ so we must exclude $\ln q = 0$, which is the same as requiring that $q\neq 1$.  And so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you have found is correct, and seems to be the most 'elegant' one, though 'elegance' is of course subject to debate. You could write
$$k=\frac{\ln(\ln(r)/\ln(q))}{\ln(i/j)}=\frac{\ln\ln r-\ln\ln q}{\ln i-\ln j}.$$